# Which is better approach?

Tags: java

I need to find subject, but it could be null. So have to do this without throwing exception. I have two approach and please suggest which is better?

```
public static String getSafeSubject(SNSEvent.SNSRecord record){
        try{
            return record.getSNS().getSubject();
        }catch (Exception e){
            return "Failed to retrieve subject";
        }
}
```

```
public static String getSafeSubject(SNSEvent.SNSRecord record){
  if(record == null || record.getSNS() == null || 
  record.getSNS().getSubject() == null){
            return "Failed to retrieve subject";
        }
        return record.getSNS().getSubject();
    }
```

Comment: I would go for the 3rd choice, where you don't call multiple time a getter but store the result, check if it is null or not and keep going deeper. But this is purely my opinion. And I believe there are no real answer to your question. Some would argue that the second is not readable (this is why I would go for the 3rd), but the first take more time due to the instanciation of an exception.

Comment: why would you create a seperate method for something like this?

Comment: if getSubject can throw an exception then getSafeSubject will have to have a try catch if not the compiler will make you throw an exception from  getSafeSubject to be caught higher up in stack. Even if you mitigate the risk of exception, the compiler will expect it.

Comment: @Luv I fell the only exception that could occurred here are unchecked exception, most likely NPE. This is why there are no `throws` declaration in the second method. I don't like to propagate unchecked exception, mainly because they don't have to be catched.

Comment: @AxelH Yes that is your intention, but the compiler does not know that null check eliminates the need for exception throwing. Since getSubject can throw an exception, it will expect it caught here or propagate up. Did you declare it as getSubject Throws Exception?

Comment: @luv, first, I didn't write the question ;) second, if `getSubject` would throw any checked exception, the second implementation would not compile.

Comment: @AxelH :) We are both saying the same thing. 2nd wont compile. so given the ops question the only possibility is #1

Comment: @Luv no, I don't agree with you, nothing tell you that the second don't compile... but we are chatting on something we can't get an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

This question isn't easy to answer and there are many things to consider. This can be up for debate, depending on the style a developer wants to use. There are pros and cons of both approaches. I will list some below:

---

Using try-catch:

Pro:

- Generally easier to read
- Faster to develop

Con:

- Hides the error
- May be slower to execute (more overhead) - this one will vary depending on guard conditions

  ---

Using guard-conditions:

Pro:

- Explicit, meaning the dev decides what is valid and what is not
- Method may throw if there are other issues

Con:

- Slower to write
- May forget to include valid guard conditions